# How to resolve SIGABRT error for ios?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, sigabrt

I have seen similar type of threads in this site, most of them suggested rebooting machine or closing xcode. But I believe this is not the concrete solution. I have attached an image, which shows occurrence of this error in my C++ project for ios. I want you people to look at it and help me. I am really stucked on it.

[image]

It will be really helpful if I get a clue to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see a thing on the screenshot...

Comment: The cause can be revealed by looking at logs in console. So post those details. In general, you can try reseting the simulator. Open `iOS Simulator` Menu in the upper left corner->Reset Content and Settings. Also try to clean your project.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen Will you please increase your font size to see that. Because whenever I am uploading larger picture it is becoming smaller. Very unlikely problem though :(

Comment: @Akash actually this an library project, an application uses this library. I am running it on the device not on simulator. I am comparatively new in ios development, I haven't found any logs in console. :(

Comment: @Naseef Ok. Did you try deleting app from device and installing again? Also try rebooting your device. To see console, you need to connect device to machine through cable. Then, go to Xcode->click organizer (top right corner)->select your device (list of devices is at left side)->click on console. Now, you can see your device's console.

Comment: Right, good idea with the font :) That's a boost assertion failure. You can see it at the last line in the console (just above the "(lldb)" line at bottom of the screenshot). I don't think it has anything to do with the IDE or simulator / device. Did you solve it just by closing XCode / rebooting the machine? If you close XCode / reboot and it's still there, it is a bug with your code.

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398649/xcode-4-and-sigabrt-error-only-for-iphone-though

Comment: @KhanhNguyen it is a rare random crash. So I couldn't reproduce it very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed. I am answering this question to let the user know about the issue. The cause of the issue was actually in the GUI. Some null pointer was the cause of the crash. So I have added null checks to resolve the crash. Null checks make code freaky but indeed a helpful way to resolve the similar type of crash as this.